# Swift: Cannot click button in subview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController, `LockScreenVC`, and am adding a `UIView` to it.
In that UIView, I am adding a `UIButton`. The button shows up, but I cannot click the button. If I add the button instead to the `LockScreenVC`, I can click the button - but it is no longer part of the `UIView`.

I've tried setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to true, but that has not done anything.

```
import UIKit



class LockScreenVC: UIViewController {
  lazy var detailContainer : UIView = {
    let v = UIView();
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    return v
  }()

  lazy var detailButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 150))
    btn.setTitle("Click Me", for: .normal)
    return btn
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    detailButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDetailButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    detailContainer.addSubview(detailButton)
    detailContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(detailContainer)
  }

  @objc func onDetailButtonPressed() {
    print("You pressed the button!")
  }
}
```

Comment: Try deleting `detailContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`?

Comment: Your `detailContainer` has no frame or constraints, so it has 0 width and 0 height.  Give it a frame or constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `detailContainer` has zero frame. Please set frame for it